# xmlslurper not coying namespace declarations

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I am having this XML,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:v2="http://ns1/" xmlns:ifx="http://www.somenamespace.org/IFX_150">
   <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <v2:AcctInqRq>
        <ifx:SomeTag></ifx:SomeTag>
    <v2:AcctInqRq>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to copy this to a test step using xmlslurper.

```
def request = new XmlSlurper().parseText( holderRequest )
                              .declareNamespace( v2:'http://ns1/', 
                                                 ifx:"http://www.somenamespace.org/IFX_150")

def xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
writer = xmlBuilder.bind {
  mkp.declareNamespace(ifx:"http://www.somenamespace.org/IFX_150",v2:"http://ns1/"
  mkp.yield request
}
```

After copy the test step looks like this

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <v2:AcctInqRq xmlns:v2="http://ns1/">
        <ifx:SomeTag xmlns:ifx="http://www.somenamespace.org/IFX_150" ></ifx:SomeTag>
    <v2:AcctInqRq>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Why is the namespace declaration in the  not being copied as is? I want all the namespaces declared on top and not in each tag. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off namespace support, and just pass them through as-is?

```
def request = new XmlSlurper( false, false ).parseText( holderRequest )
def output = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  mkp.yield request
}
```

Comment: Thanks tim, can you please help me understand the significance of false, false in XmlSlurper()?

Comment: `XmlSlurper(boolean validating, boolean namespaceAware)`